# Load X items until user reaches limit, then load X more items - Django

Tags: django, django-views

Using Django, and for example purposes, is there a way to load 50 pictures to start... Once the user reaches the end of the 50 pictures, load 50 more?

I would like to do this to decrease page loading time. If not, would anyone have a better suggestion?

I know you can do `foo = Bar.objects.all()[:50]`, but then I'm stuck to only 50. I could see setting that for maybe 300, overall, if there are a lot of images, but is there a way to load them in increments?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be interested in implementations of infinite scrolling. Example: http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html

Comment: or you can do it with ajax :)...store data on a containing element data attribute ..such as the page nr; every time you reach the end of the page, listen with jquery, get the page nr from element data, make a request to a url that is hooked to a AJAX View ..and in the ajax view get the page nr passed, you slice the Bar objects accordingly :). When you send data back to ajax, you append the objects to the template, update page nr in data attribute and voila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into [`Django Endless Pagination`](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It provides Twitter- and Digg-style pagination, with multiple and lazy pagination and optional Ajax support.

There is another application [`infinite-scroll-pagination`](https://github.com/nitely/django-infinite-scroll-pagination) which might help you in implementing the infinite scroll like functionality.

Finally, there is one more library [`infinite-scroll`](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/). Its a jQuery Plugin which you can use but currently it is no longer maintained.